# How to handle expired token in axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

this is the code:

```
var req;
axios.get('/api/v1/news?limit=1', { 
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
}).then((response) => {
    req=true;
    handleResponse(response)
}).catch(err => {
    req=false
});
```

what i wanted to do is reassign the variable req true, if request is success and false if it fails then use the refreshToken.

```
if(!req) {
    console.log("refresh token!", localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'))
    axios.get('/api/v1/news?limit=1', { 
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') // use refreshToken
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        handleResponse(response) 
    }).catch(err => {
        handleError(err)
    });
}
```

but the code never gets evaluated after the catch, basically i don't know what's best to do in this scenario after the token expires.Help?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to do with the variable `req`. Modifying a global variable within a promise chain is _weird_. I’m unsure how this variable even relates to refresh tokens…

Comment: `.axios.get` is **asynchronous** - so, you may want to show exactly where and how you are running that second piece of code